# Testing of In-app Billing application

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have made a testing application for In-app Billing,
For testing the feature of In-app Billing do i have to upload the application on market (not publish) or i can test it directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if you are using `android.test.purchased` then you need not to upload your APK.
2. if you are using your own product id then you have to upload APK and also you have to add a product with the same name you mentioned in your code. you have to publish only product (not application). Note you will not be able to buy product from your market profile ID. You have to setup a test account.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent step-by-step guide to implementing in-app billing here: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html but indeed you have to hunt a bit for an answer to your question.

You do have to upload the application to the market but you don't have to publish it. You also have to create application extras (that which is purchased) and they DO have to be published.