# my android in-app purchase not working with error product could not be purchased

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

i am developing android in-app application with static In-app Product ID: android. test. purchased that is working good and i also get 
Toast message: Thank you.You item will be appear shortly.
but in actual Product ID:com.android.example not working properly.and i don't know toast message class now i am what to do.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mainview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.comcontractsol);

    mBillingObserver = new AbstractBillingObserver(this) {

        @Override
        public void onBillingChecked(boolean supported) 
        {
            Dungeon.this.onBillingChecked(supported);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPurchaseStateChanged(String itemId, PurchaseState state) 
        {

            if(itemId.equals("android.test.purchased"))
            {       
                mainview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unlock);
                Dungeon.this.onPurchaseStateChanged(itemId, state);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondActivity.class));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(String itemId, ResponseCode response) 
        {
            Dungeon.this.onRequestPurchaseResponse(itemId, response);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want **"com.android.example"** as product id then you have to follow these steps:

1. Create .apk file and upload it in android market but **do not publish it**.
2. Find In-App purchase(items) link and create a product and **publish it**. The product name must be same as **"com.android.example"**. So I suggest you to use a meaningful product Id.

See this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702900/testing-of-in-app-billing-application/10818667#10818667)

In order to test your application, you have to create test account [see this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

Answer (score 1):

you should care about your `product_id` and `item_id`. if `product_id` cant match then error will be accure.

1.Create .apk file and upload it in android market but **do not publish** it only publish your product id.

2.now change your static id with real id and run it.